# How to find what is encrypting my files

Tags: encryption, virus

I am subject to a ransom ware attack.

What is strange is it only appears to be my NAS hard drive files that are being encrypted (and ending with a .encrypt extension).

For example, if my understanding is right, a piece of software could run on a machine and encrypt any files it has access to. This could mean, the software runs on device A, and chooses to infect files on network drives only (thus giving the appearance the machine that has no infected files is 'clean')

I am aware when a virus affects a machine, you should nuke the machine and re-install the OS.

Is there an approach to find out what is causing this, as I am guessing it is some software running some where (could be one of 4 pcs, one of 4 mobile phones or one of 2 tablets).

Comment: It would help to know which model NAS you are using, maybe it keeps some kind of logs. 
It would definitely do no harm, except for a lot of work, to reinstall every single device.

Comment: The likely culprit if it's exclusively affecting your NAS would be the NAS?

Comment: Once the files are encrypted it’s far to late to do anything about it. Time to completely wipe any possible infected device, hopefully, you have proper backups of the NAS files.

Comment: I hope you powered down the device as soon as you saw this happening.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, both mashuptwice and Seth were right (see comments in question)

> It would help to know which model NAS you are using, maybe it keeps some kind of logs. It would definitely do no harm, except for a lot of work, to reinstall every single device. – mashuptwice

> The likely culprit if it's exclusively affecting your NAS would be the NAS? – Seth

[image]

Here is a screen shot of my QNAP - I can only guess I've opened a port / didn't update it / security vulnerability because it looks like some one created a new user (called wasthere) and I guess was then able to execute some malware/injection.

https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/security/massive-qlocker-ransomware-attack-uses-7zip-to-encrypt-qnap-devices/

Comment: I won't mark this as an answer, as it explains my issue, but doesn't answer the question (but it is related and interested)!